# h2o.glm does not match glm in R for linear regressions

Tags: r, h2o

I have been working with H2O.ai (version 3.10.3.6) in combination with R.

I am struggling to replicate the results from glm with h2o.glm. I would expect exactly the same result (evaluated, in this case, in terms of mean square error), but I am seeing must worse accuracy with h2o. Since my model is Gaussian, I would expect both cases to be ordinary least squares (or maximum likelihood) regressions.

Here is my example:

```
train <- model.matrix(~., training_df)
test <- model.matrix(~., testing_df)

model1 <- glm(response ~., data=data.frame(train))
yhat1 <- predict(model1 , newdata=data.frame(test))
mse1 <- mean((testing_df$response - yhat1)^2) #5299.128

h2o_training <- as.h2o(train)[-1,]
h2o_testing <- as.h2o(test)[-1,]

model2 <- h2o.glm(x = 2:dim(h2o_training)[2], y = 1,
                  training_frame = h2o_training,
                  family = "gaussian", alpha = 0)

yhat2 <- h2o.predict(model2, h2o_testing)
yhat2 <- as.numeric(as.data.frame(yhat2)[,1])
mse2 <- mean((testing_df$response - yhat2)^2) #8791.334
```

The MSE is 60% higher for the h2o model. Is my hypothesis that glm ≈ h2o.glm wrong? I will look to provide an example dataset asap (the training dataset is confidential and 350000 rows x 350 columns).

An extra question: for some reason, as.h2o adds an extra row full of NAs, so that h2o_training and h2o_testing have an additional row. Removing it (as I do here: as.h2o(train)[-1,]) before building the model does not affect the regression performance. There are no NA values passed to either glm or h2o.glm; i.e. the training matrices do not have NA values.

Comment: From your own comments and without knowing about h2o, it would seem that h2o deals with NA's in a very different way than glm does. You should read the help files on both before posting questions

Comment: @Akabar, there are no NAs in the training matrices, so that is not the issue. I have read the documentation and h2o.glm claims to do "maximum likelihood estimation via iteratively reweighed least squares", which should give the same parameter estimates for a Guassian model as ols.

Comment: If you set the parameters carefully within h2o.glm it is possible to replicate glm, but the default settings are definitely doing different things.

Comment: More specifically, off the top of my head, look into the lambda_search and lambda parameters.  I think `lambda_search = FALSE, lambda = 0` will get you closer to what glm is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few arguments you need to set in order to get H2O's GLM to match R's GLM, since by default, they do not function the same way.  Here is an example of what you need to set to get identical results:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

path <- system.file("extdata", "prostate.csv", package = "h2o")
train <- h2o.importFile(path)

# Run GLM of VOL ~ CAPSULE + AGE + RACE + PSA + GLEASON
x <- setdiff(colnames(train), c("ID", "DPROS", "DCAPS", "VOL"))

# Train H2O GLM (designed to match R)
h2o_glmfit <- h2o.glm(y = "VOL", 
                      x = x, 
                      training_frame = train, 
                      family = "gaussian",
                      lambda = 0,
                      remove_collinear_columns = TRUE,
                      compute_p_values = TRUE,
                      solver = "IRLSM")

# Train an R GLM
r_glmfit <- glm(VOL ~ CAPSULE + AGE + RACE + PSA + GLEASON, 
                data = as.data.frame(train))
```

Here are the coefs (they match):

```
> h2o.coef(h2o_glmfit)
  Intercept     CAPSULE         AGE 
-4.35605671 -4.29056573  0.29789896 
       RACE         PSA     GLEASON 
 4.35567076  0.04945783 -0.51260829 

> coef(r_glmfit)
(Intercept)     CAPSULE         AGE 
-4.35605671 -4.29056573  0.29789896 
       RACE         PSA     GLEASON 
 4.35567076  0.04945783 -0.51260829
```

I've added a [JIRA ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4258) to add this info to the docs.

Comment: Thanks Erin. This gave me an identical result to lm. I'll now work to get the same result as glmnet.

Comment: @fifthace Set `alpha = 1.0` in H2O if you are using glmnet defaults.  Note that glmnet will probably find a different `lambda` than H2O, so you could run that first, take the best `lambda` value and then use it in `h2o.glm()`.

Comment: @ErinLeDell I was able to follow your example and produce the identical coefficients listed above; however, when I tried performing a logistic regression on CAPSULE ~ AGE + RACE + PSA + DCAPS I got different coefficients via the `h20.glm` method compared to the `glm` method; I changed family from 'gaussian' to 'binomail', but is there any other arguments I have to specify in order to obtain identical coefficients?

Answer (score 2):

> Is my hypothesis that glm ≈ h2o.glm wrong?

The algorithm of h2o.glm is different from R's glm.

h2o.glm is actually far more similar to the glmnet R package because they both support Elastic Net regularization (and two of the authors of glmnet, Hastie and Tibshirani, are advisors to H2O.ai).

When building H2O's glm, we used glmnet as a measuring stick far more so than R's glm.

Having said all that, you shouldn't expect the exact same coefficients for the result, but I would also not expect such a dramatically worse MSE.

Comment: @ Tom K, glmnet gives me almost identical results to glm, when choosing alpha using a 10-fold cross-validation to minimise the MSE. Basically, elastic net is not well suited to my example, and your explaination is not correct (in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand on the first answer and suggest:

```r
solver = "IRLSM"
lambda = 0
remove_collinear_columns = TRUE
compute_p_values = TRUE
objective_epsilon = 1e-8
max_iterations = 25
```

`glm()` uses `glm.control(epsilon = 1e-8, maxit = 25, trace = FALSE)` for any logistic regression.